# move text inside canvas element and make it centered

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to move my `div`s with the texts `hallo1` and `hallo2` to my `canvas` element and make it centered.
Does anyone have and idea on how to achieve this?

Below is code:

```
<canvas id="canvas1">hi</canvas>

<div> 
    hallo1
</div>
<div>
  hallo2
</div>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>

<div> 
    hallo1
</div>
<div>
  hallo2
</div>
<canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>

<div> 
    hallo1
</div>
<div>
  hallo2
</div>
<canvas id="canvas4"></canvas>

<div> 
    hallo1
</div>
<div>
  hallo2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

put everything in a `div` and center it with `text-align:center;`. If you still need it to be on the left side of the screen use `float:left;`, like this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/16/)

```
#everything {
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..I am trying to make text inside the circle

Comment: Good way to handle the horizontal centering issue

Comment: Thanks @vals! @user3299657 you are using [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas). You'd have to draw it up inside of that circle with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One posibility without modifying your layout is simply adjusting the position:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: -125px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/17/)

A version that adjusts to different text widths is to use 13ruce1337 answer and adjust it vertically

```
#everything {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position: static;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    top: -125px;
}
```

I have to redefine everything position, because the style to the text div would modify it

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/QhfVg/18/)